# How to develop nexus3 rundeck plugin?

Tags: plugins, bundle, rundeck, nexus3

In nexus 2.x， [Rundeck](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/05/21/nexus-and-rundeck-tools-for-devops/) can used [nexus-rundeck-plugin](https://github.com/vbehar/nexus-rundeck-plugin) working， But 3.x not working;
I want develop the plugin, But I don't how to start, I don't extension point for nexus 3.x.

Help me!!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nongfenqi/nexus3-rundeck-plugin

this nexus3 for rundeck plugin